# EF4 and SQLDependency Object

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4, sqldependency

I am trying to use EF4 with the SQLDependency object with not much luck.

I have created my own queue and service and want my WPF application to monitor this queue for data changes so that I can update the UI (opted for trying this rather than constantly querying the database).

Even though on application startup I call;

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectString, "NewResultAddedQueue");
```

My EF4 repository implementation throws an exception stating;

> {"When using SqlDependency without
>   providing an options value,
>   SqlDependency.Start() must be called
>   prior to execution of a command added
>   to the SqlDependency instance."}

Firstly, am I trying to achieve something which is not possible with EF4 or is there another approach I can take to allow my application to listen for data changes from SQL 2005??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you cannot use your own queue and service if you have more than one instance of the WPF application running. The SqlDependency infrastructure works per appdomain and if you share a queue then the instances (appdomains) will steal notifications from one another resulting in runtime mayhem. Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing, just use the default implementation (the just-in-time deployed service/queue/procedure).

The error message is pretty clear: 'When using SqlDependency **without providing an options value** yada yada yada'. So you do not provide an [`options` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224363.aspx), therefore the default is used:

> The notification request options to be
>   used by this dependency. **null to use
>   the default service**.

At the same time you're overwriting the default service in the `.Start()` call. As I said, better get the default case working first untill you're sure you understand what's going on, before venturing into non-default customized behavior, specially with something so difficult to grok as [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).

Have a look at [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) for how to use Query Notifications with LINQ. The article [SqlDependency based caching of LINQ Queries](http://rusanu.com/2010/08/04/sqldependency-based-caching-of-linq-queries/) explains how this integration works with LinqToSQL and LinqToEF, and also why you cannot actually use it with EF if LINQ is involved.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried using LinqToCache and still get the same exception thrown??

Comment: Try initializing the SqlDependency w/o a custom service/queue first and see if you can get a simple SqlCommand to work.

Comment: tried that and got it working, as you stated Query Notifications don't work with LinqToEF / Entity Framework. Thanks.